# Problems with understanding and combining linux terminal commands

Tags: linux, command

**First one :** 
We found several files and we have to copy that to *kat4* and here is code, but it doesn't seem to work corectly

```
find /home/imk-prac/  -type f -size -13c -name '*\?plik\?*' -exec cp {} /home/inf-19/aduda/\*kat1\*/\*kat2\*/\*kat4\*/ \; 2> /dev/null
```

'cp' I assume that it is copy, but I don't know what 'exec' and '{}' do.

**Second one:**

```
find /home/imk-prac/ \( -type f -size -13c -name '*\?plik\?*' \) -o\( -type d -name '\[Kolo1\]*' \)2> /dev/null
```

Generally,I understand this line (except for '2' and '-o') , but I want to add looking for files which were modificated in less that 30 days and here is what I wanted to combine with upper command :

```
find /home/imk-prac/ -type f -mtime -30 -exec ls -l {} \; > /dev/null
```

As a result I wrote it down as:

```
find /home/imk-prac/ \( -type f -size -13c -name '*\?plik\?' -mtime -30 -exec ls -l{}\) -o \( -type d -name '\[Kolo1\]*' \) 2> /dev/null
```

but it doesn't work

Moreover, I wanted to add looking for files with speciefied quantity of symbols and I found this command:

```
grep -Po '(^|\s)\S{64}(\s|$)' file
```

But I have no idea how to combine all of those 3 upper commands.

I will be grateful for any help, thank you for your time!

Comment: Do the commands work individually? I would not expect the first one to work since it tries to access `*kat1*` literally instead of with glob/wildcard matching

Comment: I didn't write it so I have no idea how it works.

Comment: It's ok if you don't understand *how* they work, but do you know that they work at all? Your combined command won't work if the individual commands don't work. You should first check that the first and the second commands work alone.

Comment: when I use this, program stops. I don't know if it looking for something or deosn't work. If you mean if there are any errors - they aren't.

Comment: There are errors, but you use `2> /dev/null` to hide them. If you remove the `2> /dev/null`, you will see the error messages.